# Perforce Ghost Depots

Tags: server, perforce, byte-order-mark, p4v

I administer a Perforce p4d server at a faculty at a university. 
Recently I accidentally created 2 Depots and 2 Groups (using a python script) with names including a BOM in front of the name. The character set of the server is utf8 (without BOM).
Both Depots show up in P4V and P4Admin, but do not properly work. The groups do show up in P4Admin but as soon as I try to select them they disappear from the list.

I have tried a lot, but was not able to get rid of them. Could someone provide me a way to delete them?

When I try to delete them I first get the Message "//WS18_EL_VRClass/... - must refer to client '_____CLIENT_UNSET_____'."

and then

"The depot contains files that are marked for add or edit.
These files must be reverted before deleting the depot."

I killed all workspaces referring to the Depots.

Any ideas?
Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unix?

Assuming you have the helix server privs to delete the groups and depost, first open a terminal window.  (In P4V, pick a folder on the workspace tab and right/context click to "open terminal window".  This will setup your P4 env variables.)

Then use "p4 group -d" and "p4 depot -d" to delete.

For example, assuming your group is "BOMoops", run:

```
p4 group -d `printf "\\357\\273\\277"`oops
```

Comment: Using printf did the trick, thanks! You are the hero of the day :D